# Determining the origins of a Perforce file with the `move/add` action.

Tags: perforce

I'm working on a script that processes the contents of a Perforce changelist.  Each file in the changelist will be handled differently depending on the action associated with it.

I've already tackled the actions `edit`, `add`, `integrate`, and `delete`.  So far, so good.  However, for `move/add` and `move/delete`, I need a reliable means of determining the file's origin and destination, respectively.  I've looked through the documentation for `p4 fstat` and haven't turned up anything of use.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at p4 filelog . It will give you the history of the moves.  The -ztag output might or might not be useful for your purposes.

Comment: Appreciate the lead.  What's odd about "move/add" in the filelog output is that the move information is stored in the change previous to when the move occurred.  Still, it's a viable approach.  Thanks.